# Failed to send picture to Web API from Angular

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I am facing problem when i trying to upload picture means I actually failed send picture file to backend(.net core). and every post request, all time I am facing `Error:HttpErrorResponse` continuously. may be my backend controller's parameter and my passing argumnet from angular are not same that why i guess. In a word, I want send picture file with form value to .net core web api from angular. I don't understand how i will do that. when i just send form it's work perfectly, when i send file with form, then found error.  Here is my code:-

`Angular HTML Form`

```
<div class="container">
    <br />
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h3>Create Player</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col text-right">
        <a href="#" routerLink="/product" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Back To Product List</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <form [formGroup]="addProductForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(addProductForm)" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        
     
   
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input formControlName="name"
               id="name"
               type="text"
               class="form-control" />
      </div>
   
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Warehouse:</label>
        <select formControlName= "warehouseId"  class="form-control">
            <option value="0">Select Warehouse</option>
            <option [ngValue]="c.id" *ngFor = "let c of war">{{c.warehouseList}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
   
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="image">Image:</label>
        <input formControlName="image"
               id="image"
               type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)"
               class="form-control" />
      </div>
   
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">ADD</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

`Angular TS File`

```
export class ProductaddComponent implements OnInit {

  addProductForm:FormGroup;
  war:Warehouse[];
  selectedFile : File = null;
 
  constructor(private service : ProductService, private fb : FormBuilder,private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addProductForm = this.fb.group({
      id:[Math.floor(Math.random()*100)],
      name:[null],
      image:[null],
      warehouseId:[null]
    });

    this.service.getAllWar().subscribe(data=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.war=data;
    })
  }

  onFileChange(fileInput: any)
  {
    this.selectedFile = <File>fileInput.target.files[0];
    const filedata = new FormData();
    filedata.append('image', this.selectedFile);
  }

  onSubmit(addProductForm)
  {
    this.service.addProduct(this.addProductForm.value).subscribe(data=>{
      this.router.navigate(["/product"])
    })
  }

}
```

`ANGULAR SERVICE`

```
  addProduct(product:ProductHandle)
  {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl+"/AddBook/",+product);

  }
```

`WEB API CONTROLLER`

```
        [HttpPost("AddBook")]
        public IActionResult Add(Products product, IFormFile image)
         {

             //clarify code

         }
```

I don't understand how will I send file with form data to API from angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your attached code, I don't see that you are sending the file to the API.

1. View

*Note: Don't think that you need to pass `addProductForm` in `onSubmit()` method as you can get `addProductForm` instance in the component.*

```
<form [formGroup]="addProductForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  ...
</form>
```

2. Component

Pass the `selectedFile` to the service.

```js
onSubmit() {
  this.service.addProduct(this.addProductForm.value, this.selectedFile).subscribe(data=>{
    this.router.navigate(["/product"])
  })
}
```

3. Service

*Merge* `product` and `file` into a `FormData` object.

```
addProduct(product: ProductHandle, file: File) {
  let formData = new FormData();

  for (let k in product) {
    formData.append(`product.${k}`, product[k]);
  }

  if (file) {
    formData.append('image', this.selectedFile);
  }
  
  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "/AddBook/", formData);
}
```

4. Controller

The API action should expect to receive the form data (via `FromForm` attribute) with `AddBookModel` type.

```cs
[HttpPost("AddBook")]
public IActionResult Add([FromForm]AddBookModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

5. Model

```cs
public class AddBookModel 
{
    public Products Product { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
}
```